# jQuery edge case in parents() test

Tags: jquery, html

just did some sample code for an employer test and I didn't pass due to edge cases :(. Any idea what those edge cases could be? The question is as follows(simplified):
Given a sample HTML document, display in an alert the deepest nesting of ul/ol objects.

e.g thefollowing code has a 4 tier nesting of ul/ol objects.

I cant think of any possible edge cases for something this specific. What could they be? Error checking is sort of non-applicable, as it only finds parent nodes that match..

Can anyone think of HTML cases where this code would not work? Just a quick description of the HTML that could cause problems would be awesome.

```js
function solution() {
    //This value will be returned
   var listDepth=0;
   //Loop through each ul (jQuery)
   $('ul').each(function(){
       var depth= $(this).parents("ul,ol").length; //find the number of ul,ol elements parented
       if (depth>listDepth)
       {
           listDepth=depth+1; //+1 includes root
       }
   });
   //Loop through each ol (jQuery)
   $('ol').each(function(){
       var depth= $(this).parents("ul,ol").length; //find the number of ul or ol elements above
       if (depth>listDepth)
       {
           listDepth=depth+1; //+1 includes root
       }
   });
  window.alert(listDepth);
   return listDepth; //return the list with most depth
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <ul>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <ol>
              <li>
                </li>
             </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  
  <button type=button onclick=solution()>Try Me </button>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```